# What are my controller in my application with a MVVM design pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, controller

I have developed a WPF-application. I have a mainwindow which inherit from Window, a tabcontrol and many tabitems in this tabcontrol which inherit from UserControl. Every tabitem has its own cs-file, where I code in C# all the businesslogic, and a XAML-file where the development of the UI is done. I also have a SQL Server with a database which i connect to trough LINQ.

So i have to write about my choice of which controller i use in my application. This is where i get confused, since i havent manually programmed a controller and i thought the ViewModel would behave like a controller in my case. Could this be correct? Can the ViewModel behave like a controller?

Comment: This is a better fit for the programmers exchange. Stack overflow is more for specific programming issues in code.

Answer (score 8):

A **controller** can send commands to its associated view to change the view's presentation of the model (e.g., by scrolling through a document). It can also send commands to the model to update the model's state (e.g., editing a document). [Model_View_Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

The **viewmodel** is a “model of the view” meaning it is an abstraction of the view that also serves in mediating between the view and the model which is the target of the view data bindings. It could be seen as a specialized aspect of what would be a controller (in the MVC pattern) that acts as a converter that changes model information into view information and passes commands from the view into the model. The view model exposes public properties, commands, and abstractions. [Model_View_ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

The introduction of **MVVMC** (MVC + MVVM) is nessesary in cases you would like to drive many similar pairs of View-ViewModel (use cases). You can then introduce controllers. [Model_View_ViewModel_Controller](http://mvvmc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 for describing cases in which you might want to choose MVVMC over vanilla MVVM

Comment: view-model is just a model used to perform data binding between view and model. What may be confusing is that MVVM pattern embeds the view-model in the controller, instead of keeping it separate (MVVMC).

Answer (score 6):

In the simplest case, have the ViewModel implement the "controller" logic. For large applications, I sometimes use an MVVMC pattern which uses a separate controller class. There has been a lot of recent support on the blogosphere for using MVVMC over MVVM.

[MVVM is dead, long live MVVMC!](http://skimp-blog.blogspot.com/2012/02/mvvm-is-dead-long-live-mvvmc.html) 
[MVMMC – MVVM grows a Controller](http://trelford.com/blog/post/MVMMC-e28093-MVVM-grows-a-Controller.aspx)