# find controller in deployed folder in visual studio

Tags: c#

I am searching the controller code in a deployed web site, but cannot find it - I have following structure in the deployed folder:

bin/

content/

fonts/

images/

models/

scripts/

views/

some other files (global.asax, packages.config, Web.config)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to find the controller code in published website?

Comment: In case you're dealing with WPF - The project does not need to have controller classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443662/what-are-my-controller-in-my-application-with-a-mvvm-design-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are compiled into an assembly. That assembly can be found in the bin folder and is named like your web project.

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Any reference to this?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are classes which compiled into assemblies (IL/DLLs) - So it's most likley that you will ***not*** find any `Controller` source-code in your deployment folders.

Search for `*.dll` files in the root website folder or explore the `bin` folder in pinpoint them.